# SQL Server substring

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need a good expression in order to select correctly parts of a field.
For example, the field can be of the type: "google_organic" or "google_campaign_HereGoesMyCode" . The part I am interested in is "organic" or "campaign" without any other addition.
So far I select with this:

```
 substring(Referer, charIndex('_',Referer)+1, len(Referer))
```

But in the case of "campaign" I select the whole thing... I don't know how to manage the existence or non-existence of the second underscore...

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to basically create a lastIndex type search using the below SQL and use the result as the length:
`len(Referer) – (charindex('_', reverse(Referer))-1)`

You can then rewrite your query as follows, although you need the result of the first charIndex so this is fairly intense:
`substring(Referer, charIndex('_',Referer)+1, (len(Referer) – (charindex('_', reverse(Referer))-1) - (charIndex('_',Referer)+1))-1 )`

I realize that this will now only work if you have 2 underscores. But you can filter which query to run based off a CASE/WHEN statement.